# Запуск нескольких процессов (web app) на heroku (free)

Tags: веб-программирование, heroku

Кто-нибудь запускал на бесплатном аккаунте heroku несколько экземпляров своего web-приложения (сервера)? Не могу понять возможно ли это и каков должен быть синтаксис procfile.

На текущий момент мой procfile:
`web: bin/start-nginx bin/myapp`

myapp запущено на порту 3001 (задано в конфиге приложения, но можно задать и в опциях cmd). И я хотел бы запустить еще одну копию на порту 3002. А на  nginx настроить upstream для обоих копий для балансировки запросов.

В доке heroku для free plan написано: 1 web dyno/1 worker dyno/1 one-off dyno maximum per app.

Но непонятно значит ли это что больше одной копии приложения я не могу запустить?
(То что я могу создать на free аккаунте несколько разных приложений это понятно, но меня интересует запуск нескольких  процессов одного приложения).

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу на собственный вопрос.
Судя по всему на heroku пользователь бесплатного плана может запустить только один web процесс и один дополнительный рабочий процесс (worker).

> Worker dynos могут быть любого типа процесса, объявленного в вашем
> Procfile, кроме "web". Рабочие dynos обычно используются для фоновых
> заданий, систем очередей и заданий с таймером.